# Orchard 1-N relationships (stops Content Item from updating)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Context: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Creating-1-n-and-n-n-relations

Here is the model of my **Track Part**:

```
    public class TrackPartRecord : ContentPartRecord
    {
        public virtual IList<TrackInformationRecord> Tracks { get; set; }
    }

    public class TrackPart : ContentPart<TrackPartRecord>
    {
        public IList<TrackInformationRecord> Tracks
        {
            get { return Record.Tracks; }
        }
    }

    public class TrackInformationRecord
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual int TrackPartId { get; set; }
        public virtual string Title { get; set; }
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<SessionInformationRecord> Sessions { get; set; }
   }

    public class SessionInformationRecord
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual int TrackId { get; set; }
        public virtual string Title { get; set; }
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime Timeslot { get; set; }
        public virtual bool HasEvaluation { get; set; }
        public virtual bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    }
```

And here is my **Migrations** to create the 3 tables (2 information records, and 1 part record):

```
    // Creating table TrackInformationRecord
    SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("TrackInformationRecord", table => table
        .Column("Id", DbType.Int32, column => column.PrimaryKey().Identity())
        .Column("TrackPartId", DbType.Int32)
        .Column("Title", DbType.String)
        .Column("Description", DbType.String)
        .Column("IsDeleted", DbType.Boolean)
    );

    // Creating table TrackPartRecord
    SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("TrackPartRecord", table => table
        .ContentPartRecord()
    );

    ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("TrackPart", builder => builder.Attachable());

    // Creating table SessionInformationRecord
    SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("SessionInformationRecord", table => table
        .Column("Id", DbType.Int32, column => column.PrimaryKey().Identity())
        .Column("TrackId", DbType.Int32)
        .Column("Title", DbType.String)
        .Column("Description", DbType.String)
        .Column("Timeslot", DbType.DateTime)
        .Column("HasEvaluation", DbType.Boolean)
        .Column("IsDeleted", DbType.Boolean)
    );
```

A Content Item attaches the Track Part (which forms the 1-n relationship) and the Track record has a list of Session records.

The problem begins when you add Tracks. The first tracks added are added. After the first update (adding the first tracks, no sessions yet), I am no longer able to update anything on the Content Item. I don't get any errors or any exceptions when I go through the code (maybe they are buried too deep in Orchard that nothing directly apparent is thrown).

When I go to the db directly and delete the Track records related to the Content Item, I am able to update everything once again.

I checked the logs and found this:

```
2013-08-14 14:15:00,882 [30] NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher - Could not execute command: UPDATE Ignite_EventsAgenda_SessionInformationRecord SET TrackInformationRecord_id = null WHERE TrackInformationRecord_id = @p0
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException (0x80004005): The column name is not valid. [ Node name (if any) = ,Column name = TrackInformationRecord_id ]
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ProcessResults(Int32 hr)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.CompileQueryPlan()
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, ResultSetOptions options)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteNonQuery(IDbCommand cmd)
2013-08-14 14:15:00,888 [30] NHibernate.Util.ADOExceptionReporter - System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException (0x80004005): The column name is not valid. [ Node name (if any) = ,Column name = TrackInformationRecord_id ]
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ProcessResults(Int32 hr)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.CompileQueryPlan()
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, ResultSetOptions options)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteNonQuery(IDbCommand cmd)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.Remove(Object id, ISessionImplementor session)
2013-08-14 14:15:00,891 [30] NHibernate.Util.ADOExceptionReporter - The column name is not valid. [ Node name (if any) = ,Column name = TrackInformationRecord_id ]
2013-08-14 14:15:00,894 [30] NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Could not synchronize database state with session
NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not delete collection: [Ignite.EventsAgenda.Models.TrackInformationRecord.Sessions#1][SQL: UPDATE Ignite_EventsAgenda_SessionInformationRecord SET TrackInformationRecord_id = null WHERE TrackInformationRecord_id = @p0] ---> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: The column name is not valid. [ Node name (if any) = ,Column name = TrackInformationRecord_id ]
```

Firstly, I don't know why I'm getting the "column name is not valid" issue.

Second, I don't get this line: UPDATE Ignite_EventsAgenda_SessionInformationRecord SET TrackInformationRecord_id = null WHERE TrackInformationRecord_id = @p0

Where did it get the column name TrackInformationRecord_id?

Any help or advise would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, should to name it with the slash, and the types can be with the record class name instead of the int. You also should set the Datetime as nullable: Datetime?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try it this way (I omitted the Session for simplicity but you could copy the same):

```
public class TrackPartRecord : ContentPartRecord
{
    public virtual IList<TrackInformationRecord> Tracks { get; set; }
}

public class TrackInformationRecord
{
    // Own properties
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    // Relations properties
    public virtual TrackPartRecord TrackPartRecord { get; set; }
}
```

And in the migration:

```
        SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("TrackPartRecord", t => t
            .ContentPartRecord()
            );

        SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("TrackInformationRecord", t => t
            .Column<int>("Id", column => column.PrimaryKey().NotNull())
            .Column<int>("TrackPartRecord_Id")
            .Column<string>("Title", c => c.WithLength(50).NotNull())
            .Column<string>("Description", c => c.NotNull())
            .Column<bool>("IsDeleted")
           );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TrackInformationRecord
{
    public virtual IList<SessionInformationRecord> Sessions { get; set; }
}
```

... says that a parent `TrackInformationRecord` has many child `Sessions`.  I'm guessing that Orchard uses Fluent NHibernate's auto mapping under the covers to generate the NHibernate mappings.  FluentNH's default column name for a one-to-many relationship is `{classNameOfParent}_id`.  Hence `TrackInformationRecord_id`, and hence the error - you never created a column with that name.

I'm not familiar with Orchard, so I don't know if it provides a way to customize this behavior.  FluentNH provides a way (https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Auto-mapping#overrides), but whether Orchard exposes that functionality to you or not, I don't know.  If you find a place to put mapping overrides, something like this should work:

```
public class TrackInformationRecordOverride
    : IAutoMappingOverride<TrackInformationRecord>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<TrackInformationRecord> mapping)
    {
        mapping.HasMany(x => x.Sessions)
            .KeyColumn("TrackId"); // ... assuming TrackId is the column you wanted.
    }
}
```